# AWS security groups equivalent in azure

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

what is the AWS security groups equivalent in azure

if there is any in azure is this only for the PaaS services or also for IaaS ?

Comment: would you explain what AWS security groups are?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Amazon EC2 Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html), a security group is just a single point for firewall settings applied to a given instance:

> A security group acts as a firewall that controls the traffic allowed
>   to reach one or more instances. When you launch an instance, you
>   assign it one or more security groups. You add rules to each security
>   group that control traffic for the instance.

In Windows Azure you have to set these rules on a per-instance or per-service basis, there is no way to define some rules and apply them automatically to all instances.

But you can use PowerShell [cmdlets](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureAddFirewallRules-352de4ed) for automating this task for your services.

Firewall rules apply mostly for PaaS: for your web/worker role services and for SQL Azure. In case of IaaS there are two sides: your VM with custom software firewall (depending upon your OS etc.) and the endpoints you create and manage in Azure Portal that relay in- and outbound traffic to your VM.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Network security groups and other related improvements were announced today:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-new-marketplace-network-improvements-new-batch-service-automation-service-more

Answer (score 0):

**Network Security group** in Azure is the option you are looking for. But there is no option to create it directly. But can be created while creating Virtual Machines and can be associated with multiple Virtual Machines. For more detail,

http://tehcbase.com/aws-security-group-equivalent-in-microsoft-azure/